# Finding mean and variance using moment generating function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be observations of a random sample of size $n=2$ from a distribution
>   with p.d.f. $f(x) = 60x^2 (1 − x)^3, 0 < x < 1$.
>
> Find the mean and variance of $Y = X_1 + X_2$.

Would I solve this problem by using the moment generating function to find the $E(X)$ and $Var(X)$ of $X$ and multiplying by $2$ (since it's $x_1 + x_2$) or can I find the $E(X)$ by integrating $f(x) \cdot x$ from $0$ to $1$ and $Var(X)$ in simliar fashion using $Var(X) = (E(X))^2 - E(X^2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a lot easier than that.  Recall that $${\rm E}[Y] = {\rm E}[X_1] + {\rm E}[X_2]$$ by linearity of expectation.  We also have $${\rm Var}[Y] = {\rm Var}[X_1] + {\rm Var}[X_2] + 2 {\rm Cov}[X_1, X_2].$$

If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are observations of a random sample drawn from a common distribution $f$, it is reasonable to assume they are independent and identically distributed.  Therefore, ${\rm Cov}[X_1, X_2] = 0$, and all you have to do for this question is calculate the expected value and variance of the given distribution $f$--these will then be the values of ${\rm E}[X_i]$ and ${\rm Var}[X_i]$, respectively, for $i = 1, 2$.

Comment: And $$E(x_i) =\int_{0}^1 x * f(x)\; dx?$$

Comment: Yes.  More generally, $${\rm E}[X^k] = \int_{x=0}^1 x^k f_X(x) \, dx.$$  Calculate the first and second raw moments $(k = 1, 2)$ then use the formula for variance.  You can also recognize $f$ as a beta distribution with appropriate parameters.